# rhel 8.0 repo where packages' name with "module" and "+" not recognized when repolist

Tags: rhel, repository

I have a strange problem. As i mentioned in title, rhel 8.0 repo where packages' name with "module" and "+" not recognized.

At yum server, there are 10 packages.

```
[root@centos77 rhel8]# pwd
/var/www/html/yum/rhel8
[root@centos77 rhel8]# 
[root@centos77 rhel8]# ls
buildah-1.11.6-4.module+el8.1.1+5259+bcdd613a.x86_64.rpm                     preupgrade-assistant-2.6.1-1.el6.noarch.rpm
containernetworking-plugins-0.8.3-4.module+el8.1.1+5259+bcdd613a.x86_64.rpm  preupgrade-assistant-contents-0.6.41-2.el6.noarch (1).rpm
containers-common-0.1.40-8.module+el8.1.1+5351+506397b0.x86_64.rpm           python-rhsm-1.18.7-1.el6_9.x86_64.rpm
container-selinux-2.124.0-1.module+el8.1.1+5259+bcdd613a.noarch.rpm          python-rhsm-certificates-1.18.7-1.el6_9.x86_64.rpm
fuse-overlayfs-0.7.2-1.module+el8.1.1+5259+bcdd613a.x86_64.rpm               repodata
grep-2.20-2.el7.x86_64.rpm
[root@centos77 rhel8]# 
[root@centos77 rhel8]# ls |grep rpm -c
10
```

Then, i create a repo file on test server with rhel8.0 system. There is a local.repo which uses ISO as packages source. Below is detailed information:

```
[root@rhel8 yum.repos.d]# ls
bak  local.repo  redhat.repo  security.repo
[root@rhel8 yum.repos.d]# 
[root@rhel8 yum.repos.d]# 
[root@rhel8 yum.repos.d]# cat local.repo 
[base]
name=base
baseurl=file:///mnt/BaseOS
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0

[appstream]
name=appstream
baseurl=file:///mnt/AppStream
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
[root@rhel8 yum.repos.d]# 
[root@rhel8 yum.repos.d]# cat security.repo 
[security]
name=security
baseurl=http://192.168.88.177/yum/rhel8
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
[root@rhel8 yum.repos.d]#
```

But the problem is, when i run "yum repolist", the security.repo only display 6 packages, not as many as that at yum server.

```
[root@rhel8 yum.repos.d]# yum repolist
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:08:45 ago on Thu 09 Jul 2020 05:26:14 PM CST.
repo id                           repo name                               status
appstream                         appstream                               4,672
base                              base                                    1,658
security                          security                                5
```

But when i run "yum repolist --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=security" ,there are 10 packages, as many as that at yum server.
And i have check, those packages not recoginized are below, and there are "module" and "+" in the names.

```
buildah-1.11.6-4.module+el8.1.1+5259+bcdd613a.x86_64.rpm
containernetworking-plugins-0.8.3-4.module+el8.1.1+5259+bcdd613a.x86_64.rpm
containers-common-0.1.40-8.module+el8.1.1+5351+506397b0.x86_64.rpm
container-selinux-2.124.0-1.module+el8.1.1+5259+bcdd613a.noarch.rpm
fuse-overlayfs-0.7.2-1.module+el8.1.1+5259+bcdd613a.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Did you run `createrepo_c`?

Comment: @jsbillings yes, i have run createrepo_c